# Dual citizen (Australian/US) traveling to India with an Australian passport and visa. US passport hasn't arrived yet, how to get back in?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, dual-nationality, australian-citizens

I'm traveling to India for the holidays. I've booked the trip and visa using my Australian passport information.

I recently became a US citizen and applied for a US passport. It still hasn't come in yet. I don't have a Green Card anymore (I gave it up, keeping with normal protocol, during my citizenship ceremony).

I'm returning by way of Canada. What should I do to get back into the US with my Australian passport?

Comment: You can enter Canada with your Australian visa and continue into the USA with the same passport (there is no penalty for doing so) although the law prefers you use your USA passport to enter USA.

Comment: Technically there is no _penalty_ but you _will_ be delayed at the border while your citizenship is verified. This may take two minutes or several hours. But you still get to sit in detention for a while, which could be considered its own penalty. You also get a CBP officer yelling at you and a brochure explaning why you need to travel with your US passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton does that work even if I'm flying in from Toronto to NYC?

Comment: In that case you'll hit US preclearance. The problem there is that the delay at CBP could possibly cause you to miss your flight, even if the delay is short.

Comment: How long has it been since you applied for your passport? It might still arrive before you depart for your holiday. Will anyone remain behind in the US who can forward it to you by courier if it arrives after you depart?

Comment: Do you have a copy of your naturalization certificate? I would take that.

Comment: @mkennedy They take the original naturalization certificate when you apply for your first passport.

Comment: I'm going to get it sent to my place in Toronto if it arrives after I get here. Fingers crossed that works!

Comment: @ohmystarisfading2013 any update?

Comment: OP has not returned since asking.